# Construction of small resolution of a double point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is the hypersurface in $\mathbb{A}^4$ defined by

$$x_1 x_4-x_2 x_3 +f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=0$$

where $f$ is a polynomial whose monomial terms are all of degree $\geq 3$. So the origin $(0,0,0,0)$ is a double point of $X$.

If $f=0$, a small resolution of this double point could be easily constructed. Suppose the homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^1$ are $(y_0,y_1)$. Let the variety $\hat{X}$ in $\mathbb{A}^4 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ be defined as,
$$x_1 y_0+x_2 y_1=0$$
$$x_3 y_0+x_4 y_1=0$$
Then there is a natural projection $\hat{X} \rightarrow X$ which replaces the double point of $X$ by a $\mathbb{P}^1$. However if $f$ is not zero, does there exist an explicit construction as above?

Comment: The small resolution may only exist as an algebraic space.

Comment: what are $\mathbf{A}^4$ and $\mathbf{P}^1$?

Comment: @Surb Sorry for the late reply, $\mathbb{A}^4$ is the affine space and $\mathbb{P}^1$ is the projective space.

Comment: @JasonStarr Do you know any references about this? i.e. construct the small resolution as an algebraic space.

Comment: There is an article of Artin about this.  I do not have the precise reference at the moment.